# Set unattended-upgrades non-interactively

Tags: unattended-upgrades

In Ubuntu 16/18 I would like to set unattended-upgrades to yes non-interactively.

I only know about `dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades` and it isn't.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: Answer to a similar question: https://askubuntu.com/a/1479580/249627

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`

Look for the following line:

`APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";`

'1' means enabled, '0' means disabled. Edit the config file to the setting you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo EDITOR='sed -Ei "
    s|unattended-upgrades/enable_auto_updates=.+|unattended-upgrades/enable_auto_updates=\"no\"|
    "' dpkg-reconfigure -f editor unattended-upgrades
```

Related answer: [How do you set a locale non-interactively on Debian/Ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/a/1114285)